# How can I remove cookie values stored as array in js.cookie.min.js jQuery?

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have the following cookie values stored as array.

[image: Cookies values]

I can read the value from jQuery like this.

```
Cookies.get("cart["+id+"]");// id is variable stored as 1000006-1-2
```

But when I remove cookie value, it can not be removed from the cart array.

```
Cookies.remove("cart["+id+"]");
```

How can I remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the **expires** in the past ( < 2018). Like this :

```
document.cookie = name + '=;Path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1900 00:00:01 GMT;';
```